# how to tell hibernate, if battery low

Tags: power-management, gnome-shell, battery, gsettings

I need to tell to `power-manager` (with `gnome-shell`) , if battery is low,`pm-hibernate` will be run. Now i want to tell via `gsettings commmand`.

How can i do it?

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action hibernate`

Comment: how to change it with percantage : http://askubuntu.com/questions/92794/how-to-change-critically-low-battery-value